# Can anyone access my computer if I use tor browser?

Tags: web-browser, tor

Today I was told that if I use tor browser, hackers may access my Computer and can delete or copy files from my Hard Drive.

Is it really true? Can hackers access my computer If I use tor?

Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: If the TOR browser was infected because it got it from a bad location, then yes. Browsers themselves do not allow people access to your machine.

Comment: Also using JS might help them (drive by downloads and all), which is why the Tor Browser Bundle comes with NoScript.

Comment: @Alpha3031, what you are talking about isn't special to Tor. It is just a risk of being on the Web.

Comment: @NeilSmithline True, but people using TOR would also have more reason to worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TOR browser bundle is just one piece of (fairly) complex software and thus will contain bugs. It is based on the Firefox browser which regular receives bug fixes, even for remote code execution and [this bug](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2015/08/06/firefox-exploit-found-in-the-wild/) allowed an attacker to access local files in Firefox (but not TOR browser).

If it is possible to such bugs reside in a currently fully patched version of the TOR browser bundle but is not publicly known and I'm sure you will not get such information from the agencies which will use these bugs in the context of attacks or [investigations](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2015/01/did-feds-mount-a-sustained-attack-on-tor-to-decloak-crime-suspects/).

Thus it is the best to not only use the TOR browser bundle but also use it from a system with no sensitive data on it. Also the system should not be able to reach any possible vulnerable systems inside your local network, because then typical Web 2.0 attacks like CSRF, XSS... in these systems could be used, like [attacking the router](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2104380/attack-campaign-compromises-300000-home-routers-alters-dns-settings.html) or attacks [using the local printer server](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/486606).